# Running code after Azure Data Factory Pipeline completes

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to execute certain rest commands after my ADF Pipeline has finished executing.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a .net custom activity at the end of your pipeline process? The other alternative could be to use PowerShell to look for a completed pipeline and trigger your REST command.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities